# Droid Losing Values (Android SDK)

Tags: android

Shorter version of the problem now that I've had a Droid user run some tests for me.

My app is mainly a webview with thing's like image uploading that require more than that.

In the webview's onPageStarted I call a method to show the image picker if the user is at a specific URL.  In the onActivityResult I get the filename that they want to upload and pass that along with the url they are at (it contains important querystrings) to another method in a new thread.

For some reason for Droid users the url is null or an empty string.  I've tried settings a global variable of the url before showing the image picker, but in the onActivityResult that value is an empty string.  I've tried doing a webView.getUrl(), but again, no value.

This is working fine for everyone except Droid users.

Any ideas why this is happening or where I can put the url so it isn't lost?